Question on nestorovs theorem dealing with the oracle lower bound for the iteration complexity
Right now I am studying the nesterov accelrated gradient where my objective is convex and has lipschitz continuous gradients. In my lecture notes it is mentioned that the NAG is special in the sense that it delivers an algorithm which achieves $\mathcal{O}(1/k^2)$ iteration complexity which is optimal because nesterov proved a lower bound on the iteration complexity which is also in $\mathcal{O}(1/k^2)$.
So I looked into the book of nesterov and found the important theorem which seems to be the origin for the statements in my lecture notes.
Here is the theorem from the book of Nesterov "Lectures on Convex Optimization", Section 2.1.2, p.71:

There are two things which are not clear to me:

I have found sources which completely omit the part that this lower bound only holds for $k \leq \frac{1}{2}(n-1)$. I have read somewhere that it holds for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, do I miss something? If it really doesn't hold for all $k$ then I wouldn't understand why we should call NAG optimal in this sense. It is rather "optimal in the beginning" or not?
If I am not misunderstanding what $\mathcal{F}_L^{\infty,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ means than this Theorem only holds if my $f$ is infinitely differentiable but the functions we are considering in my lecture are just convex and continuously differentiable with Lipschitz gradients. Can we still apply the Theorem?


For 1, as far as I know this theorem is indeed “optimal in the beginning,” indeed most people neglect such details when summarizing the theorem. For 2, the fact that there exists a smooth function that provides the counterexample is what is wanted. The fact that the function is infinitely differentiable is even better, since it shows the example does not rely on certain higher order derivatives not existing. Once you start allowing weirder functions with some derivatives nonexistent, then bounds tend to change, for example, Nesterov has another theorem for the no smooth case.

Note the theorem is not about “your function $f$.” It is about one particular function on which a class of algorithms necessarily fail to go faster than a certain speed. You could better say the theorem is about “your algorithm“ because if you come up with a new algorithm (within Nesterovs class), and think you can prove it always gets faster speed, either your proof is wrong or your assumptions are so stringent that they do not even allow Nesterov’s function, which is infinitely differentiable and hence a very well-behaved function.

Thank you very much, now the two points are clear. I have one more question. Nesterov writes on page 73:
"The above theorem is valid only under the assumption that the number of steps of the iterative scheme is not too large as compared with the dimension of the space of variables"
Is this really the case for examples in large scale machine learning or for other big problems? Is this the case in practice that our $k$ really stays smaller than $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)$?

This holds for some problems, but not all. I have collected my thoughts on this into an answer.

This answer includes a summary of some of my comments.
Nesterov's Theorem 2.1.7 is a converse result that constructs a particular convex and smooth function $f$ for which no algorithm (in a large class of algorithms) can compute a near-minimum faster than a certain speed. Specifically, no such algorithm can guarantee an optimality gap smaller than a value proportional to $1/k^2$ for the "beginning" steps $k$, specifically, for $k \leq (n-1)/2$.

Indeed the Nesterov Theorem 2.1.7 holds only for the "beginning" steps  $k\leq (n-1)/2$. I have also noticed that most people neglect this detail when summarizing the theorem. As you mention, Nesterov discusses this assumption: He writes that it is common to have the dimension $n$ larger than the number of iterations $k_{max}$. A typical example is $n=10^6$ and $k_{max}=10^4$. Of course, not all settings are like this. You might use the same number of iterations on a problem that has only 100 variables ($n=100, k_{max}=10^4$).  One important fact about Nesterov's Theorem 2.1.7 is that he has a matching achievability theorem that shows one particular algorithm (the accelerated gradient algorithm you mention) can be used for smooth functions and provably makes progress proportional to $1/k^2$ for all steps $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, including the beginning steps and also including steps $k>(n-1)/2$.

The fact that Nesterov's example smooth function $f$ is also an  infinitely differentiable function makes his Theorem 2.1.7 even stronger:  It shows that we cannot improve the rate of progress faster than $1/k^2$ (for the beginning steps $k$) even if we assume our function is so well-behaved that it is infinitely differentiable.  However, we must assume our function is differentiable and smooth: Nesterov has a corresponding converse theorem for convex but nonsmooth problems. He constructs another convex function $g$ that is not differentiable and shows the performance bounds are now proportional to $1/\sqrt{k}$ for "beginning $k$," rather than $1/k^2$. These results collectively help to explain why we need more iterations for nonsmooth problems as compared to smooth problems.


If my memory is correct, Nesterov calls his function $f$ the "worst function in the world." I think he also calls his function $g$ the "worst function in the world." This is funny and I think it helps get his point across: Existence of these functions places fundamental limits on the performance of a wide class of algorithms. If you invent a new algorithm that falls within this wide class, then you cannot prove your algorithm makes progress faster than Nesterov's bounds unless you make your assumptions so restrictive that they exclude his $f$ and/or $g$ functions.
